# undefined method for text_field in ruby on rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails

```
<%= f.text_field :quantity_available, :readonly => "readonly",:class=>"mg-text-field" %>
```

error:

> *undefined method `quantity_available' for #<:0xaf32b824>*

In the new form I have shown "quantity_available" whose value I am getting through jquery and this field is only for displaying purpose so this has not been saved in model but I want to do same in edit form in which I am getting error as

how to resolve this?

Comment: May be "quantity_available" is not a column in the table. You can define it in the model as attr_accessor :quantity_available

Answer (score 2):

You can define the field in the Model without it needing to be a persisted column in the table.

```
class Model < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessor :quantity_available

  # other stuff here

end
```

Answer (score 0):

For that purpose you can use text_field_tag. For more check on http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/FormTagHelper.html

```
<%= text_field_tag 'quantity_available',nil, class: "mg-text-field", readonly: true %>
```